# How can I fill a 2d array recursively?

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion

I have a string filled with 9 numbers. I want to fill a 3x3 array with the numbers. I've managed to do it using a foreach and 2 for loops, but I feel this is quite messy. How can I modify my code to recursively enter the values into the array? This is my code currently:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[3, 3];

if(key.Length < 9 || key.Length > 9)
{
    keyfield.GetComponent<InputField>().text = " Key Not Valid";
}
else
{        
    foreach(char c in key)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                matrix[j, k] = c - 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I'm working with Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just iterate over the `char`s in your `key` and assign them to the array, one field at a time. It's just a matter of calculating the correct columns and rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    int row = i / 3;
    int col = i % 3;
    matrix[row, col] = (int)key[i];
}
```

Also note that neither the code in your question nor the code in my answer solves the problem in a recursive way. Recursion is given when a method calls itself directly or indirectly, which is not required to solve this particular problem.

Comment: If this solved your problem, accepting the answer would be appreciated :-)